# Why can't I see custom profile fields when I edit an event participant record

Tags: civievent, joomla, participants

I'm using civiCRM on Joomla and I need to edit a participant record to change a selection for a custom field. When I edit the record it does not show the custom field selections. Is this possible, if so, How do I view and edit their selections?

Thanks!
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you check if there is any JS error on browser console? What version of CiviCRM are you using?

Comment: My version is 4.7.29 the only error I see in the  Firefox web console is "Empty string passed to getElementById()."

Comment: Is there any custom module or plugin enabled?

Comment: I have the following extensions installed:

    TinyMCE (com.aghstrategies.tinymce) version 1.4
    Save time preparing newsletters: Fancy tokens for upcoming events, contribution pages, and forms (com.pogstone.fancytokens) version 4.0
    CiviMobile (com.webaccessglobal.module.civimobile) version 2.0
    Simple Donate (com.webaccessglobal.simpledonate) version 2.0
    ExtendedReport (nz.co.fuzion.extendedreport) version 3.0
    CiviDiscount (org.civicrm.module.cividiscount) version 3.3
    Gender Self-Identify (org.woolman.genderselfidentify) version 1.2

Comment: I have no browser plug-ins

Comment: perhaps provide some more details/screenshots eg of your custom field set up. I.e. to confirm the custom fields ARE for participants rather than some other entity.

Comment: I added screen shots of my custom field set.

Comment: Are the custom fields editable? A custom field could be set to view only? And is the custom group set to a specific participant role/event type? And if so is the participant record from a different type?

Comment: I figured it out. It was showing but the fields were collapsed.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. It was showing but the fields were collapsed.

Comment: You can mark your own answer as completed!